# How to read the length of a UTF-16 codepoint in an endian-agnostic way

Tags: c++, unicode, endianness, utf-16

How can I step through a UTF-16 string along its codepoints if I don't know its endianess ahead of time? At this point in my code it's assumed that endianess has already been converted to whatever is used by the current architecture and I just want to walk from one codepoint to the next.

Comment: If it is already converted, what is the problem?

Comment: If it's already converted to native, just use a pointer to a 16-bit integer type and read each word directly.

Comment: Unicode doesn't care about Endianness, just so you know.

Comment: And there is no such thing as "UTF-16 codepoints", either.  UTFs are just encodings for codepoint values. The actual elements of a UTF string are known as "codeunits" instead, where the number in the UTF name denotes the bit size of its codeunits (UTF-8 uses 8bit codeunits, UTF-16 uses 16bit codeunits, and UTF-32 uses 32bit codeunits). Unicode defines the codepoints themselves, whereas UTFs define how those codepoints are represented in bits.

Comment: Btw, both "code point" and "code unit" are noun phrases consisting of two words each, not single words.

Comment: Relevant? http://commandcenter.blogspot.no/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only count reliably if you know the endianness of your data.

This could be achieved by making sure that the data starts with a [unicode BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Representations_of_byte_order_marks_by_encoding):  it's `0xFE 0xFF` for big endian and `0xFF 0xFE` for little endian.  So with a 16 bit char `wc` that you read, (`wc>>8==0xFE`) will tell you the endian.

Without BOM you can never be sure if it's BE or LE, except if you find some encoding inconsistencies in [surrogate pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U.2B10000_to_U.2B10FFFF) which would show that your endianness assumption is wrong (i.e. on 16 bit char is in the `0xD800-0xDFFF` range and the other doesn't match the conditions to form a surrogate pair).

You can also attempt to make an educated guess by using some basic statistics, using newlines (if it's multi-line text) or null distribution accross the text (See for example [this library](https://www.autoitconsulting.com/site/development/utf-8-utf-16-text-encoding-detection-library/)).  But whatever you find, you can't really be sure you have identified the correct endian.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. Consider the byte sequence `0xD8 0x3D 0xDE 0x00`:

- If it's read as UTF-16BE, it's a single codepoint: `U+1F600` ()
- If it's read as UTF-16LE, it's two codepoints: `U+3DD8` `U+00DE` (㷘Þ)

Both interpretations are perfectly valid, and there is no way to distinguish between them without some byte order indicator.

Comment: that's why the BOM is used in some contexts.